# Return values from FORTRAN 77 Code to C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, fortran, return-value

I've been trying this thing out for 2 days and can't make it work.

I was trying to do the same thing this guy did: ->  [returning real values from fortran77 dll to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365958/returning-real-values-from-fortran77-dll-to-c-sharp)

I've done everything exactly as he done. Even compiled with the same parameters in the same compiler.

But I get "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." error.

Need help!

Here is my C# code :

```
 [DllImport("Lks.dll",
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void DON(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double DAA,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double DBB,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double DCC
        );

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //double TIME = 100.0;
        double DAA = 5.5;
        double DBB = 7;
        double DCC = 9;
        //START( ENERIN, VAL1);
        DON(DAA, DBB, DCC);

        Console.Write("val1 = " + DAA);
        Console.Write("val2 = " + DCC);
        Debug.WriteLine("VAR = " + DBB.ToString());
        Console.Write("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
```

And here is my FORTRAN 77 code:

```
*$pragma aux DON "DON" export parm(value*8, reference, reference)


  SUBROUTINE DON(DAA,DBB,DCC)
  REAL*8, DAA,DBB,DCC
  DBB=DAA+1
  DCC=DBB+1 
  RETURN
  END
```

Everything looks the same to me. So I think maybe is a VS2010 problem.

Comment: and your fortran compiler is...?  (Probable cause is a mismatch in pass by value (C#)/pass by reference (Fortran))

Comment: This `*$pragma aux ...` is only understood by the Open Watcom F77 compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*$pragma aux ...` auxiliary pragmas are only understood by the Open Watcom FORTRAN 77 compiler. Any other compiler would simply ignore them as a comments. The intent of the pragma from your code sample is to make `DAA` pass-by-value and to fix the external name of the routine symbol to `DON` (otherwise the Fortran compiler might redecorate it to something similar to `DON_` or `don__`). The other two arguments still remain pass-by-reference. The `P/Invoke` interface in your question specifies all of them as pass-by-value. You need to add the `ref` keyword:

```
[DllImport("Lks.dll",
           CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void DON(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] double DAA,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] ref double DBB,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] ref double DCC
);
```

Should you use any other Fortran compiler that does not understand OW's pragmas, then all arguments would be pass-by-reference and hence you need to apply `ref` to all arguments:

```
[DllImport("Lks.dll",
           CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void DON(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] ref double DAA,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] ref double DBB,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] ref double DCC
);
```

Be aware of possible calling conventions mismatch and symbol decorations/mangling. Check with your Fortran compiler's manual.

Comment: @Roiw, so you are really using the Open Watcom compiler suite? Why not use something more modern like `gfortran` for Win32?

Comment: Yes! I'm using  Open Watcom. I tried gfortran but It doesn't have an IDE and looked like it was more difficult to learn. That's why I picked Open Watcom.